# How to update a set?

Tags: python, indexing, set

Seems like using update should be pretty straight forward, and I think that I'm using it correctly, so it must be an error dealing with types or something else.

But anyway, here's the sit:

I'm doing coursework for a Coursera course (needless to say, answers minimizes or occluding code most helpful!) and am stuck on the last problem.  The task is to return a set that contains all the documents which contain all the words in a query. The function takes an inverseIndex, a dictionary containing words as keys and the documents containing those words as values ex: `{'a':[0,1],'be':[0,1,4].....}`

The way I've attempted to implement this is pretty simple: get a set of sets, where each of the sets contains the list of document IDs, and then call .intersections(sets) to merge the sets into a set containing only the doc IDs of docs that contain all words in the query.

```
def andSearch(inverseIndex, query):

    sets = set()
    s = set()
    for word in query:
        s.update(inverseIndex[word])
        print(inverseIndex[word])
    print s
    s.intersection(*sets)

    return s
```

Unfortunately, this returns all the documents in the inverseIndex when it should only return the index '3'.

terminal output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

What's wrong?

Thanks so much!

---

```
sets = []
s = set()
for word in query:
    sets.append(inverseIndex[word])
print sets
s.intersection(*sets)

return s
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
set([])
logout
```

Comment: `sets` seems to be empty, you should be adding your little sets to it each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `update` inside the loop. So, on each iteration you add the new pages to `s`. But you need to intersect those pages, because you need the pages, each of which contains all the words (not 'at least one word'). So you need to `intersect` on each iteration instead of updating.

Also, I'm not getting why you need `sets` at all.

This should work:

```
def andSearch(inverseIndex, query):
    return set.intersection(*(set(inverseIndex[word]) for word in query))
```

This just produces the array of `set`s:

```
>>> [set(ii[word]) for word in query]
[set([0, 1]), set([0, 1, 4])]
```

And then I just call `set.intersection` to intersect them all.

---

About your question update.

It happens because `s` is empty.

Consider this example:

```
>>> s = set()
>>> s.intersection([1,2,3],[2,3,4])
set([])
```

To intersect sets just use `set.intersection`. But it accepts only sets as arguments. So you should convert lists of pages to sets of pages, or keep pages as sets in the dictionary.

Comment: Getting: attributeError: set has no attribute intersect.

Comment: I see, and I wonder why the method I'd been using wasn't working. You've obviously answered my post, but could you also explain why the code I'm posted at the bottom of my original question isn't working?

Comment: You are using `update`. So elements of the sets are not intersected, but added. Try executing this line in the interpreter to understand `s = set([0,1]); s.update([5,6,7]); print s`. So in the end you have all the pages where at least one word exists (as if the word is in this page, it would be added to resultant set).

Comment: @goldisfine Ah, I see the update of the question. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: Ugh, that makes sense. Thanks so much ovgolovin! Really appreciate you taking the time to help with that additional question; shows that you're about teaching.

Comment: @goldisfine I love teaching. A lot of my friends relent to being taught. But this site really absorbs people who are wiling to learn and who are willing to explain. This is really a lot of joy to explain something!